# Connected components of a certain real homogeneous space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $m>0$ be a natural number.
Consider the following semisimple algebraic groups over ${\mathbb{R}}$:
$$ G={\mathrm{SU}}(2m,4m),\ \ H={\mathrm{SU}}(2m,2m)\times{\mathrm{SU}}(2m). $$
We embed $H$ into $G$ "block-diagonally" and consider the homogeneous space $X=G/H$,
which is an affine variety over ${\mathbb{R}}$.
Using Galois cohomology, I can compute the number of connected components of $X({\mathbb{R}})$:
$$ \#\pi_0(X({\mathbb{R}}))=m+1.  $$
Probably it is possible to obtain this result from classical algebraic geometry.

**Question.** How can one obtain this result from classical algebraic geometry, without Galois cohomology?